# Lazy loading of attributes

Tags: python

How would you implement lazy load of object attributes, i.e. if attributes are accessed but don't exist yet, some object method is called which is supposed to load these?

My first attempt is

```
def lazyload(cls):
    def _getattr(obj, attr):
        if "_loaded" not in obj.__dict__:
            obj._loaded=True
            try:
                obj.load()
            except Exception as e:
                raise Exception("Load method failed when trying to access attribute '{}' of object\n{}".format(attr, e))
            if attr not in obj.__dict__:
                AttributeError("No attribute '{}' in '{}' (after loading)".format(attr, type(obj))) # TODO: infinite recursion if obj fails
            return getattr(obj, attr)
        else:
            raise AttributeError("No attribute '{}' in '{}' (already loaded)".format(attr, type(obj)))

    cls.__getattr__=_getattr
    return cls

@lazyload
class Test:
    def load(self):
         self.x=1

t=Test()     # not loaded yet
print(t.x)   # will load as x isnt known yet
```

I will make lazyload specific to certain attribute names only.
As I havent done much meta-classing yet, I'm not sure if that is the right approach.
What would you suggest?

Comment: *"Metaclasses are deeper magic than 99% of users should ever worry about. If you wonder whether you need them, you don't." - TP*. I think that a property as suggested by Daniel would be better.

Comment: I'm using this recipe http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576563-cached-property/

Comment: @Rik: I'm not thinking whether I need meta-classes but rather, how to solve the lazyload problem. Daniels example doesn't quite solve it yet, since it is read-only and I don't want duplicate code lines for each occurence. Can it be adjusted?

Comment: See also the `lazy` package, available [on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/lazy/), and [GitHub](https://github.com/stefanholek/lazy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like a simple `property` would do the trick better:

```
@property
def my_attribute():
    if not hasattr(self, '_my_attribute'):
        do_expensive_operation_to_get_attribute()
    return self._my_attribute
```

Comment: Sounds neat, but now the question is whether it can be made convenient? I also need writable properties. And more importantly, can I pack this into a nice notation without rewriting the same 4 lines of code many times?

Comment: Can I even write `my_attribute=lazyload(load_method)` in the class definition or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `lazy` from `django/utils/functionals.py`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/utils/functional