# Optimization of a simple lazy load for an attribute in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

This is the property definition I use to lazy load the element attribute of my Element class, borrowed from [This post on Python lazy loading.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275470/lazy-loading-of-attributes)

```
@property
def element(self):
    if not hasattr(self, "_element"):
        self._element = self.wait.wait_for_element_to_be_visible(self.locator)
    return self._element
```

It looks for the attribute `_element` if it doesn't find it then it goes and looks for it. If the attribute is there then it just returns the attribute without looking for it as its already been loaded in.

I've changed the `if` to be:

```
 if self._element is None:
       self._element = self.wait.wait_for_element_to_be_visible(self.locator)
 return self._element
```

Is it more pythonic to see if the attribute exists, or to set `_element` to None in the `__init__` method and then check for that instead?

Doing it the second way also seems better for debugging purposes in IntelliJ as there seems to be a strange loading issue that freezes the tests if I expand my Element object and it starts introspection to display attributes and their values.

Comment: Is `self._element = None` a legitimate state?

Comment: @mypetlion It is, especially in this instance. I was just curious at the performance impacts or any pitfalls that could arise. Although I don't see any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My definition of a pythonic solution is the one that's most likely to help a future maintainer understand what's going on when they come across this code (most times it's the same person who wrote it but long after they have it in their memory). Here's some things I might ask myself if I was coming in cold.

### 1. hasattr

- self._element is not in `__init__`, is this because it's set somewhere else?
- Every access checks for the attribute, does that mean it's expecting it to be deleted at some point so it can refresh? Why else is it checked every time?
- hasattr will search up the chain of MRO, are we actually looking for something?

### 2. is None

- Found self._element in `__init__` being set to None. Am I allowed to set it to None again to get fresh values? The _ in _element is hinting no.

### 2a. is _Missing

If None is a valid result, use a sentinel instead.

```
class _Missing:
    pass

def __init__():
    self._element = _Missing
```

### 3. One shot descriptor

Property produces what is known as a data descriptor. It will ignore attributes of the instance and go straight to the classes dictionary (otherwise `__set__` won't be able to do it's thing). Here we make our own non-data descriptor (only defines `__get__`), which won't skip the instances dictionary. This means the instances attribute can be set. Deleting the instance attribute will result in a refreshed value on the next invocation.

```
class LazyLoadElement:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        instance.element = instance.wait.wait_for_element_to_be_visible(instance.locator)
        return instance.element

class MyClass:
    element = LazyLoadElement()

mc = MyClass()

print(mc.element)  # Instance doesn't have element, so classes descriptor is invoked
print(mc.element)  # Instance does have element, returns value
del mc.element     # Remove element from instances __dict__
print(mc.element)  # Classes descriptor is invoked again
```

- What's the intention of the LazyLoadElement? Name says it all
- Will it refresh after the first call? Nope, it's going to hit  the instance attribute not search up the MRO.

Pythonic is a little arm wavy because it needs to make assumptions about who is reading the code at a future date. Out of the 2 original options, number 2 seems most likely to get maintainers up to speed. 3 is my fav though, mainly because once it's loaded there's no more function calls.

Comment: For option 3, is it correct in saying that if the `element` property is called it will recompute its value?

Comment: Nope. After the first invocation of `element`, the instances `__dict__` will now have an entry for `element` who's value is the result of the wait function. That's the technical way of saying it's now a bog standard value assignment as if `my_class.element = instance.wait.wait_for_element_to_be_visible(instance.locator)` was run from the start.